# Python decorator for a class method to update class variable

Tags: python, python-decorators

how can I implement a decorator in python and use it in a Python class for example on one of the class methods so that it can modify the class variable (results) at run time? in the code the decorator should add stuff to results dictionary when do_something is invoked and done running

```
import mydecorator 
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = {}

    @mydecorator
    def do_something():
        # do something
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: essentially i want to time my class methods and save the time in a variable which is bounded to the class so that i can have access to that once i invoke any of the class methods. I can write a decorator to print the time but i don't know how to append the time to a class variable. I did research but all i got is how to print time or how to get access to a class variable in my decorator, my problem is how to update class state through a decorator

Comment: That isn't a classmethod, and that isn't a class variable. That is an *instance* method and an *instance* variable. In any case, what exactly isn't working? Please show your current approach and how it isn't working, **exactly**.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956937/6565435

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to are known as setters. Setters essentially are methods used to set the values of an object's instance variables. To achieve that using decorators, certain rules need to be followed:

- The method's name must be the same as the variable.
- The decorator `@name.setter` must precede its definition.

You can easily implement a setter in the class you created:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = {}

    @results.setter
    def results(self,dictIn):
        self.results = dictIn
```

As you can see, not creating a setter in the above example wouldn't have changed much, but in some cases, you might want the behaviour to be different when the value of a data member is being modified. That basically is the use of setters.